# A server with the specified hostname could not be found in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I switch out `AFnetworking` API from `ASIHTTPRequest` in my app for connection error issues.

But now I'm getting connection error in `AFNetworking`. How can I resolve this?

```
Printing description of error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the
specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x1553bab0
{NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.com/oauth/token,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.com/oauth/token, NSLocalizedDescription=A server
with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x1553b2c0 "A server
with the specified hostname could not be found."} (lldb)
```

Comment: So you had connection errors with the old framework and you have connection errors with the new framework?

Comment: @Droppy yes Can you please advice me how to resolve this

Comment: check the URL you are providing, is this URL exist https://example.com/oauth/token

Comment: @WildFire i dint get you? please explain

Comment: URL for which you are trying to make connection.

Comment: Have you tried using this extension? https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client

Comment: @WildFire : just i gaving sample url. Can you please explain where is in problem

Comment: @Droppy no i tried with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Comment: The link I provided was an extension to AFNetworking to make working with OAuth2 easier.  I think it's something you need to use.

Comment: @Droppy sorry i dint get you then what do to? bz i switched to AFnetowkring changes are done my whole project.Now getting same issues.

Comment: Did you find solution to your problem? I am also facing the same challenge, please let me know what to do. Thanks

Comment: @2vision2 is this resolved ? if yes, how ?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Before i build with  AFNetworking source in my app without cocoapods AFNetworking. After i installed from basic step issue solved.

Answer (score 5):

Basically it's a server side issue. This error occur when your server is not responding or your server looks like in sleep mode.

I have also fetch this same issues many time. But, in my case when i switch to another WiFi network or Switch ON/OFF WiFi then it was automatically solved. Please try that and let us know your comments.

Thanks!

Comment: What about if there is no network connection and the name server cannot be reached?

Comment: @mohit thanks for your reply. But same api in andriod its working fine that's why im confusing. Can you please give any ref for this issues

Comment: @Mohit after 2 to 3mins when tried once again its wokring fine .Some times only im getting this issue

Comment: Yes This is server side issue i have also faced many times :)

Comment: i am also getting exactly same issue its been a long time still not resolved. I  cannot just say it's a server side issue because it works fine for Android also for website. I have issue only in IOS. If it's a server side issue , can you please give a hint whats it is about. Is this related to open connection for long time, gzip or what ? Please suggest !!

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I am facing the same problem, did you solve it! the same link is working fine in Safari wherase I am getting 1003 error in my app any idea?

Comment: @MoMo is it still occurring? Try resetting your device, that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I was also running into this problem. Resetting the device fixed the issue for me. I believe it may have something to do with DNS Pollution. I didn't have the issue after resetting so I couldn't keep testing, but I have read that turning on airplane mode and turning it off again works too.